# Implementing cross-cutting concepts into LOB/DI application

Tags: dependency-injection, application-design, lob

I am currently creating a small personal windows (desktop) .NET [LOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_business) application and I want to use the opportunity to increase my knowledge and experience with [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I've separated my application into model, DAO and GUI parts but I am wondering how to implement some cross-cutting concepts such as:

- currently logged on user - used for:

  - asserting rights - in some parts of the application I check if the user has necessary rights
  - auditing - recording user actions into a separate database table
  - etc
- current application parameters (loaded from configuration file or table) - used for:

  - defining business strategy
  - defining UI (theme for example)
  - etc
- logging to file/database log - used for:

  - logging UI actions (clicking on buttons etc.)
  - logging business processes (results of calculations, strategy decisions etc.)
  - logging infrastructure stuff (SQL used to for CRUD operations)
  - etc

At the moment I can think of several ways to provide this information:

- Using static properties - UserEntity.Current, Configuration.Current, Logger.Current, etc.

  - Pros:

    - Simple to implement
    - Simple to use
  - Cons:

    - Gets messy
    - It is unclear which part of the application uses what
    - Can not be used if you need finer granularity (for example if for some processes in the application you need to override current values)
- Using [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) - giving each class which needs this information a property/ctor parameter

  - Pros:

    - It is clear for each class what it needs
    - It is easy to unit test
  - Cons:

    - It just seems to explode constructors
    - Makes problems if class needs to have a default constructors
    - Difficult to setup when classes get instantiated by 3rd party (XAML)
- Using [ServiceLocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)

  - Pros:

    - Easy to setup
    - Easy to use
  - Cons:

    - It is unclear which part of the application uses what
    - Difficult to setup finer granularity (but not impossible)

I am currently leaning towards ServiceLocator as I've worked with it before and it worked quite nice. However I am concerned about loss of control. It gets very easy to just reach for the service locator instead of trying to fix a design problem.

Can somebody provide their experiences/knowledge?

Comment: The best way to apply cross-cutting concerns is by applying decorators to your services. [This article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) describes an attractive way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like perfect case to start with [aspect-oriented](/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented) approach. Your application's LOB will be designed according to business functional requirements that has been cross-cutted with different non-functional requirements: authentication, audit, logging, etc.

In same time, some of *current application requirements* could be solved by [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection). To start, I recommend first to identify [*composition root*](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). For example, in [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) applications it’s the `Application.OnStartup` method. In case if you are able to identify *composition root* it is better to avoid [service-locator](/questions/tagged/service-locator). *Service locator* will add unneeded complexity while maintaining and testing, because it could resolve literally anything, thus dependency management will be complicated.

Next step, to decide: should *dependency injection* and *aspect-oriented approaches* be separated or combined. Both approaches has benefits and drawbacks.

While choosing *separated* approach you could use [postsharp](/questions/tagged/postsharp) with a lot of benefits: great samples and documentation, community and ready to use aspects. But nothing come for free, *postsharp* has only limited number of features in free version and complicated integration with [continues-integration](/questions/tagged/continues-integration).

Another solution: combine [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) with [dynamic-proxy](/questions/tagged/dynamic-proxy). As long as you follow conception: program to an interface, not an implementation — you will achieve all requirements. Benefits: one place to wire all components. There are two major drawbacks: first *dynamic proxy* is quite limited itself, second — integration between *dependency injection container* and *dynamic proxy* — for some container it already exists, for others not. Example: [Ninject extension Interception](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception), or StructureMap and Interception.

I recommend you to take a look at following resources to find more answers yourself:
* Book [AOP in .NET: Practical Aspect-Oriented Programming by Matthew D. Groves](http://www.manning.com/groves/): first chapter available for free 
* Book [Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann](http://www.manning.com/seemann/): well-written book about *dependency injection*, and chapter #9 dedicated to interception, approach that I found quite useful in cases that you had described in question. Author of book also has [an excellent blog dedicated to *dependency injection*](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) and video about [*aspect-oriented* programming with *dependency Injection*](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GOTO/GOTO-2011-Copenhagen/CPH-Aspect-Oriented-Programming-with-Dependency-Injection).

Comment: PostSharp is especially useful when wanting to apply AOP to a legacy application. If you start fresh, I would suggest going with DI, since PostSharp makes writing unit tests extremely hard (since PostSharp compiles the BL and aspects together).

Comment: You forgot to mention a third option, namely dependency-injection with decorators. This is my preferred way of applying cross-cutting concerns. (nice answer though)

Comment: Totally agree, _aspect composition_ could be tricky to test, because you have to cover with tests not only each advice (aspect function), but also how they interact and sequence how they integrate. Regarding _dependency-injection with decorators_: it's very close to interception with _dependency container_, difference is where cross-cutting is defined: at separate class (i.e. _decorator_), or while using container configuration (proxy and interceptor).

Comment: I agree: interception and decorators are very alike. Interception is more flexible,  while decorators are cleaner. Some containers are unfortunately bad in handling decorators.